# Is there a way to use capybara's find outside of a before

Tags: html, capybara

I'm writing tests for a set of up down arrows(divs) that change an inputs value, but act slightly differently depending on the numbers value. I'm writing tests to make sure it's working but seem to only be able to use find("div[id='up-arrow-div']").click inside of befores. Is there a way click this div inside the it?

Code as is:

```
describe "up-arrow all the way down" do
  before do
    find("div[id='up-arrow-div']").click
  end
  it "should increase the input value by 5 if you click the up-arrow button" do
    find_field('amount').value.should eq "95"
  end
end
```

Code as I'd like it:

```
describe "up-arrow all the way down" do
  it "should increase the input value by 5 if you click the up-arrow button" do
    find("div[id='up-arrow-div']").click
    find_field('amount').value.should eq "95"
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this not working? How is it failing?

Comment: The code as is is working, after more research it looks like I can't do it the way I'd have liked to do it.

Comment: I think it should be possible. I am suprised if you can't do it like that.